How to Set FastCGI parameters using HTTP Headers from OAuth2-Proxy in Nginx Ingress to my PHP App
I'm having trouble passing the authenticated user's identity to the backend application.
Deployed on Kubernetes

Nginx Ingress
OAuth2-Proxy
PHP app (backend)

Problem: I've configured Nginx Ingress to authenticate users through OAuth2-Proxy. The headers from OAuth2-Proxy, such as X-Auth-Request-Email, X-Auth-Request-Preferred-Username, X-Auth-Request-Access-Token, and X-Auth-Request-User, are correctly passed to the backend i.e. my PHP application. However, when I attempt to set the fastcgi_param REMOTE_USER using the HTTP headers received in the response, nothing appears on the frontend.
Ingress Configuration snippet:

Verification I can see headers:



I can see FastCGI parameters:

But I do not see the REMOTE_USER set:

index.php in my app:
<?php
echo "<h1>Received Headers</h1>";
foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
    echo "<p><strong>$name:</strong> $value</p>";
}

echo "<h1>FastCGI Parameters</h1>";
foreach ($_SERVER as $name => $value) {
    echo "<p><strong>$name:</strong> $value</p>";
}

if (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'])) {
    echo "<h1>Authenticated User</h1>";
    echo "<p><strong>REMOTE_USER:</strong> " . $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'] . "</p>";
} else {
    echo "<h1>Authenticated User</h1>";
    echo "<p><strong>REMOTE_USER:</strong> Not Set</p>";
}

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_AUTH_REQUEST_PREFERRED_USERNAME'])) {
    echo "<h1>Preferred Username</h1>";
    echo "<p><strong>X-Auth-Request-Preferred-Username:</strong> " . $_SERVER['HTTP_X_AUTH_REQUEST_PREFERRED_USERNAME'] . "</p>";
} else {
    echo "<h1>Preferred Username</h1>";
    echo "<p><strong>X-Auth-Request-Preferred-Username:</strong> Not Set</p>";
}
?>

I've tried using Lua to set the X-Remote-User header based on the X-Auth-Request-Preferred-Username. And then attempted to directly set fastcgi_param REMOTE_USER using various Nginx configuration approaches, but the REMOTE_USER is not visible on the frontend.
Question: How can I correctly set the fastcgi_param REMOTE_USER using the headers received from OAuth2-Proxy? Is there a specific way to pass this information from Nginx Ingress to the backend via FastCGI that I'm missing?
Additional Context: Any advice on how to troubleshoot or correctly configure this would be greatly appreciated, especially if you have experience with PHP, Nginx Ingress, FastCGI, and OAuth2-Proxy integration.
